# PHP updating data of database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying out a code to update data of the database using a PHP form. My code doesn't seem to work because all I am getting is "Could not update data." and when i check the table in the database there was no update done. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code

index.php

```
<body>

<form method="post" action="update.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">ID</td>
<td><input name="emp_id" type="text" id="emp_id"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100">Date of Birth</td>
<td><input name="birth" type="date" id="birth"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100">Educational Background</td>
<td><input name="edu" type="text" id="edu"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

update.php

```
<?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
        if(! $conn )
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
            $birth = $_POST['birth'];
            $edu = $_POST['edu'];

    $sql = "UPDATE vtiger_leadscf 
                SET birth = '$birth', 
                edu = '$edu'
                WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id'" ;

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: You are using both mysqli and mysql.
Use either of them

Answer (score 0):

replace your query

```
 $sql = "UPDATE vtiger_leadscf 
                SET birth = '".$birth."', 
                edu = '".$edu."'
                WHERE emp_id = ".$emp_id ;
```